# Log 4j - Not able to see the debug method class for log 4 j

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need to implement Log4j in the selenium, but am not able to call debug method?

Below mentioned log4j properties file:

```js
#Application logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=D:\\selenium\\Module 07
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwIsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per screenshot, you imported java.util.logger but not log4j logger. So import

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm) is the simple example which helps you